# Having trouble running two loops at the same time python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I want to run two loops at the same time in python (first_mainloop(), second_mainloop()), I use threading but it doesn't work at this situation (only first loop runs and after it gets closed second loops starts running)  any ideas?

````
import threading
import runpy
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
import os
def first_mainloop():
    p1 = PhotoImage(file='Screenshot_13-removebg-preview.png')
    root.iconphoto(False, p1)
    frameCnt = 12
    frames = [PhotoImage(file='light_ai_design_by_gleb.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(frameCnt)]
    # set window size
    root.geometry("500x400")
    root.title("Assistant")
    def update(ind):

        frame = frames[ind]
        ind += 1
        if ind == frameCnt:
            ind = 0
        label.configure(image=frame)
        root.after(100, update, ind)
    label = Label(root)
    label.pack()
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.after(0, update, 0)
    root.mainloop()

def second_mainloop():
    runpy.run_path("main.py")

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=first_mainloop())
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=second_mainloop())
thread2.start() ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in parentheses, because when you write this `thread1 = threading.Thread(target=first_mainloop())`, you call the function. So remove the brackets, it should be something like: `thread1 = threading.Thread(target=first_mainloop)`

Here is great explanation of your problem: https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-create-a-thread-to-run-a-function-in-parallel/